# Bluemix Secure Gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, rhel7, secure-gateway

I want to install Secure Gateway client on RHEL7 but I'm getting this error:

file / from install of ibm-securegateway-client-1.6.1-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64

```
[root@vm24x50 ibm_stuff]# rpm -ivf ibm-securegateway-client-1.6.1+client_x86_64.rpm
Preparing packages...   
file / from install of ibm-securegateway-client-1.6.1-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64
```

Any ideas how I can go solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing the Secure Gateway Client on RHEL 7, you must provide the `--force` option with the installation command.  The documentation for installing on RHEL can be found [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_025.html#sg_031).

Comment: Thank you. I installed the client but now when I try to manually start it I get an error:
`[secgwadmin@vm24x50 client]$ node lib/secgwclient.js --t <token>  <gateway_id>
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'log4js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/ibm/securegateway/client/lib/utils/logging.js:26:18)`
...
Any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: The 'Cannot find module` error is due to an issue with the `npm install` that should have automatically run during the client installation.  From within the client folder, try running `npm install`.  Assuming that is successful, that should resolve the `Cannot find module` error.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it